# How GCM/FCM alternatives work internally to overcome OS challenges

Tags: android, push-notification

For devices that don't have Google Play Services, there are a few options to be able to receive push notifications. 
Those options can be Baidu in China, Pushy, Facebook own push notifications, etc.

But I cannot understand how is that even possible to overcome those two main problems :

1. Since we cannot have an "SDK" of some sort like the Google Play Service on a device-level, our only option is to integrate it on an app-level. This means, we cannot have one socket connection to the push server that would be mutual for all apps, like the GCM does. Instead, we need to have as many socket connections alive as the number of apps installed.
2. Even if we close an eye on problem number 1, to make that connection survive Doze and App Standby, we would have to handle them in a Foreground Service, which is the only way to guarantee its running even after killing the app, or when the device enters Doze state.
   But how come we don't see the notification of a foreground service in the notification bar in Chinese phones, or apps that use Pushy for example?
   Are they simply polling the push server periodically? with AlarmManager (marked with setAndAllowWhileIdle) and a BroadcastReceiver ? that would be too resource-heavy and inefficient.